# Java: Design pattern for method that gets called excessively

Tags: java, concurrency

What's the best practice in Java to protect a method from being called excessively, while still keeping it non-blocking?

My usecase is a custom buffer for audio data. The buffer's method through which data can be polled from it must be non-blocking, and it is acceptable for the method to return null when no data is available. It's not acceptable for the method to be blocking, so I do not want to make it synchronized.
When the method is called excessively the sound quality decreases. So how can I protect the method under heavy load, without relying on callers to behave themselves?

My current approach is to remember the timestamp of the last poll and return null if it's shorter ago than 3ms, but this feels a bit "hacky"...

Comment: Wouldn't documenting it suffice? Set out some guidelines instead of restricting it to a seemingly arbitrary frequency.

Comment: Look up Token Bucket on Wikipedia

Comment: You can use some kind of caching mechanism with 'time to live' setting ie. EHCACHE, but.. under the roof - it will work similarly to your actual code

Comment: synchronized and blocking are two different concepts. Do you want to make it thread safe (maximum one thread in the method) or do you want the method to return immediately if there is no data (non-blocking)

Comment: As written in the question it should return immediately.

Comment: Try the Jetty [BlockingArrayQueue](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/BlockingArrayQueue.java). It does not lock anything if it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for "java design pattern", I would say that having a thread busy poll is somewhat of an anti-pattern.  Not in general, but it's not really something one sees a ton.

When I have seen it, it's pretty much always up to the caller to limit their call speed.  I assume the caller has a shared interest in keeping the sound quality good and doesn't want to burn CPU to jeopardize that.  Can you just document your method and leave it up to the caller?

However, to answer your question, I would invert the responsibility, and have the consumer register a callback that is fed on a schedule (3ms??) by your buffer.  So instead of the consumer pulling, the producer pushes.

The nascent "reactive streams" specification (http://www.reactive-streams.org/) has an implementation of this, with the addition that consumer must request to the producer how many items it can handle and then the producer feeds them as they become available.

https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams/blob/master/api/src/main/java/org/reactivestreams/Subscription.java

Even if that's not directly applicable, it might give you some ideas.

Good luck.

Comment: The notification model you are describing is the type of implementation we want to get rid of, for reasons that are outside of the scope of this thread. I agree with you that the caller has a shared interest, but I have been asked to provide a rock solid implementation that "just works", so I'd like to not have to rely on documentation. Anyway, I gather from your post that I am not missing an obvious design pattern I should be using, so I mark this one as accepted. Thanks to all for the help anyway...

Answer (score 3):

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) does just that.  It is non-blocking and returns null if no messages are available.  Either that or a [ConcurrentLinkedDequeue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html)

Comment: I am using a ConcurrentLinked Queue in the buffer, and in fact I am only polling from that queue when the public poll method gets called, but this seems to be enough for the audio quality to be affected. With the 3ms workaround the results are much better.

Comment: So is the CLQ not sufficient or is the best available option atm and you were hoping there would be something else.

Comment: The CLQ works as excpected, and my current solution does the job, I was really only wondering if there was a smarter/nicer pattern I could apply...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to use the Java NIO framework here?

A little more information would help too.
Data does arrive from where, who is interested in the data, ...

i.e. if data arrives from network you could simply fill buffers with the data (with some sort of LRU map and time-information for the parts) and the tasks needing the data could just read out those buffers?

Comment: The data is taken from a ConcurrentLinkedQueue which is in turn fed by converted data taken from yet another queue. So this is pretty much exactly what you are describing. The only question is how I could protect this design from the task needing the data

Comment: So you have a setup where one thread writes data and n other threads read it. By data, do you mean ByteBuffers, byte-arrays?

Comment: If it's ByteBuffers i'd consider adding plain arrays into the queue and have the consumers wrap those into a ByteBuffer of their own. (well not solving the problem i guess)

Comment: Maybe you could add another object bound to the queue, have another task synchronize on this object and interrupt it if you have written new data into the queue. All consumers which didn't get any new data but are still waiting for it may then sync on this same object and woken up with notifyAll.. but maybe there are better ways to do this.